# Consuming from two channels simultaneously leads to goroutines hogging up my RAM

Tags: go, concurrency

I am quite new to concurrency and I decided to run a few parts of my http handler in goroutines and it started eating up my RAM and froze my computer.

This is what I am trying to do:

My handler has these two function calls

```
qChan := cloneQuestions(currentFormView.QuestionObjects, currentForm.Id, currentForm.VersionNumber, now)

rChan := cloneRules(currentFormView.RuleObjects, currentForm.Id, currentForm.VersionNumber, now)
```

Both these function calls are defined in a file called helpers.go and they return channels of structs to their callers.

This is the function definition of cloneQuestions and clonedRules follows the same pattern as this one

```
func cloneQuestions(questions []question.Model, formID string, versionNumber int, now time.Time) <-chan question.Model {
    out := make(chan question.Model)

    go func() {
        for _, currentQuestion := range questions {
            out <- getClonedQuestion(currentQuestion, formID, versionNumber, now)
        }
        close(out)
    }()

    return out
}

    func getClonedQuestion(currentQuestion question.Model, formID string, versionNumber int, now time.Time) question.Model {
    newOptionsArray := cloneQuestionOptions(currentQuestion, formID, now)


    return currentQuestion
}
```

`cloneRules` is very similar to this

After calling these two functions in my handler and storing their returned channels in qChan and rChan variables as described above I run an infinite loop to consume values from both the channels simultaneously and break out of the loop once I stop receiving values from both the channels, here is the code

```
for {
    select {
    case clonedQuestion := <-qChan:
        insertQuestionToFormTxn := h.service.Mongo.GetAppendTxn(ctx, form.COLLECTION, currentForm.FormID, "questions", clonedQuestion.Id, clonedQuestion.Order)

        newQuestionTxn := h.service.Mongo.GetNewTxn(ctx, question.COLLECTION, clonedQuestion, clonedQuestion.Id)
        // collect all the txns in the arrray
        array = append(array, insertQuestionToFormTxn, newQuestionTxn)
    case clonedRule := <-rChan:

        newRuleTxn := h.service.Mongo.GetNewTxn(ctx, rule.COLLECTION, clonedRule, clonedRule.Id)
        // collect all the txns in the arrray
        array = append(array, insertRuleToFormTxn, newRuleTxn)
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

When I make a request to this handler and I run htop side by side I saw that it started filling up my RAM and froze my machine, why is this happening?

Comment: You never break from this loop. Why do you have a `default:` in the `switch` statement? The `break` only breaks from the `switch`, but it’s in a `default` so it does nothing.

Comment: I thought the default case would be invoked when I stop getting results from both the channels

Comment: What would it mean to “stop getting results”? It’s either blocking waiting for values, or it isn’t. The only way to indicate that there are no more values is to close the channels, but closing the channels results in non blocking reads as well, so the default wouldn’t be useful then either.

Answer (score 1):

As @JimB suggests, remove the `default` clause from the select statement, as it is causing a tight-loop, which pegs your CPU.

Select's optional default allows for non-blocking polling of channels. In your case, you want to wait for either channel item. And in most use cases, blocking is better than polling.

If you are worried the service may appear asleep due to blocking, you can add a timer channel to show liveliness e.g.

```
t := time.NewTicker(time.Minute)
for {
    select {
    case i := <-ch:
        log.Println("got item:", i)
    case <-t.C:
        log.Println("I'm not dead yet!")
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DmOK3AiyRu-)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without profiling your program or, even better, tracing it. If you enable tracing you will easily see where your code allocates most of the memory.

But there are two things one may notice from your implementation:

1. Why cloning the objects? Are other goroutines accessing them? Otherwise you could just use the objects directly and avoid the cost of cloning.
2. Are you sure that you need channels and goroutines to process `questions` and `rules` objects? It seems to me that in `cloneQuestions` function you don't perform any I/O operation, in fact you just clone the object and sent it to channel. Finally, you take those objects and append all of them into a single slice (that is `array`). Thus the algorithm looks like intrinsically sequential and you will not get any performance benefit from using concurrency.